# Do orthogonal vectors yield orthogonal bivectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra

Suppose we have a (say, ordered) set $$(X_1, \ldots X_k)$$ of pairwise orthogonal vectors, say with span $S$. This determines a set
$$(Y_{ij})_{1 \leq i < j \leq n}, \qquad Y_{ij} := X_i \wedge X_j,$$
which by construction is a basis of the space $\Lambda^2 S$ of bivectors.

Is there a sense in which the bivectors $Y_{ij}$ are themselves (pairwise) orthogonal?

Comment: My background is in signal processing, where 'information' means a lot. I am trying to find if there is a way to get 'more information' from an orthogonal matrix by some manipulation. If I consider uncorrelated variable as orthogonal matrix can independent variable mean something else? Sorry, all these may be non-sense.

Comment: Exactly. An orthogonal matrix I can think as a set of vectors. So can we get some information from the set by manipulating?

Comment: May be I can put it this way: If I have a model of the orthogonal set of vectors which have a unknown factor due to noise, can we learn more on the space of bivectors?

Comment: Thank you. Intuitively, I feel the same way "f you already have expressions for the orthogonal vectors (even with an unknown factor), I don't think you're going to learn more by taking exterior products" But the question is why? Do you have a idea?

Comment: What is the set of bivectors? If we have an (ordered) set of vectors $(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$, do you mean the set of bivectors $Y_{ij} := X_i \wedge X_j$, $1 \leq i < j \leq n$, say?

Comment: Yes. In fact, I was looking for some relation if exist; between a set of X and say Y as you mentioned.

Comment: I've rewritten your question so that its intent is (what I find to be) a bit clearer. Please modify/revert any changes that don't preserve your intent.